# Weird behavior in Visual C++ in reading stream to a double

Tags: c++, stream, double, runtime

I am encountering a weird issue in visual studio 2022 (version 17.7.1).  In the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istringstream istr("1e-07 3");
    double xx = 0;
    int yy = 0;
    istr >> xx >> yy;
    cout << "xx = " << xx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program will print differently based on runtime library and platform toolset:

```
Toolset v143, Multi-threaded Debug or Multi-threaded: 1e-06
Toolset V143, Multi-threaded Debug DLL or Multi-threaded DLL: 1e-07
Toolset v142, Multi-threaded Debug or Multi-threaded: 1e-07
Toolset V142, Multi-threaded Debug DLL or Multi-threaded DLL: 1e-07
```

Can someone confirm this?  I would be amazed if this is an actual bug in the compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting 1e-06 in 17.8.0 Preview 1.0 too. Odd :-)

Comment: Thanks, Ted.  This is really bad and can cause major issues in the real world, Microsoft.  Imagine we read a file and then save the data back.

Comment: clang16.0.6 on Windows "clang-cl /Od /Zi /MTd .\a.cpp" produced 1e-07. Same with /MDd switch

Comment: Please file a bug with Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, I just filed a bug report with Microsoft.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1998863, is there a link to your bug report?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Weird-behavior-in-Visual-C-in-reading-/10445082

Comment: Reported Microsoft STL issue: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3980

Comment: this bug is now fixed in  VS 2022 17.9 Preview 1: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Weird-behavior-in-Visual-C-in-reading-/10445082

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is fixed in vs 17.8.1

Answer (score 1):

The function `_Parse_fp_with_locale` in [`xlocnum`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1754c8229120ae607a335ee37a5afa1f9f8737b2/stl/inc/xlocnum#L1018) is returning `"010e-7"` whereas using the Debug DLL runtime it returns the correct value `"01e-7"`. Someone has already submitted a fix https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/3982. For now you can workaround the issue by not putting leading zeroes on your exponents.

If you're feeling really brave then commenting out the following block on line 1018 of `xlocnum` seems to fix the issue:

```
if (_Seendigit) {
    *_Ptr++ = '0'; // put one back
}
```

[Visual studio 2022 17.9 will contain this fix](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Weird-behavior-in-Visual-C-in-reading-/10445082#T-N10460838)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please comment why DLL-runtimes do not contain the bug? Is it because they were built from an older version of Microsoft STL?

Comment: @Fedor you'd have to ask Microsoft, I'm not sure they publish this details anywhere